# Datetimepicker. Doesn't show any timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

I have a situation with datetimepicker. It doesn't show any timer when I click the first icon. The second works. The chrome browser not showing any errors in the development console. Any suggestions ?

```
<div class="input-append form-group datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type='text' data-format="hh:mm:ss" class="form-control" name="evstime" placeholder="Adauga ora" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-append form-group datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" data-format="hh:mm:ss" class="form-control" name="evstime" placeholder="Adauga ora"/>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false 
    });
});  

    <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/calendar.js'></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
```

Comment: create working demo like js fiddle

Comment: check any console error

Comment: [Check here!!..](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add these as CDNs.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And use only datepicker:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.form-control').datepicker({
            pickDate: false 
        });
    });  
</script>
```

In general, check you library dependencies. Here is more information about it: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I suppose your js code $(function... is a <script></script> Tag ? I will add it to the code. Also do you see any console log errors ? One more thing. You need the datepicker on an "input" field. Look at the code update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were trying to initialise the `datetimepicker` on the `<div>` instead of the `<input>` itself. Try changing your `HTML` to:

```
<div class="input-append form-group">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type='text' data-format="hh:mm:ss" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="evstime" placeholder="Adauga ora" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-append form-group datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" data-format="hh:mm:ss" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="evstime" placeholder="Adauga ora"/>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the `datetimepicker` included on the `class` attribute of each `input`..

And in order to initialise all `datetimepicker` controls at once, use:

```
$('.datetimepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false 
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

`pickDate: false` will [disable your `datetimepicker`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/version3/), [remove this attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/5097/) and everything should work as expected.

Comment: nothing happens... i don't know why, but the result is the same

Comment: "nothing happens" because `pickDate: false` [disables](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/version3/) the `datetimepicker`. Check my update.